# extracting last name from a name string in ORACLE DB

Tags: sql, database, string, oracle

I am writing a small query to extract all last names from a bunch of Author name database. Names on file will contain first and middle name, or just first name.

Ex: John Smith 
    John T. Smith

So I cannot search purely by just after the first space... But I know for sure that the lastname should be from the END to the first space from the right side of the string. I don't really care about first name.

This is what I currently have...

```
select [name], LEFT([name], CHARINDEX(' ', [name] + ' ')-1) as firstName,
SUBSTRING([name], charindex(' ', [name]+' ') + 1, LEN([name])) as lastName
from Author 
;
```

I am quite new to sql, any help is highly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: for those who ever come across this need for help, this line helps:

```
select substr(t.string,instr(t.string,' ',-1)+1) last_word
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have to deal with compound surnames like Charles De Gaulle, Martin Van Buren, Kristin Scott Thomas, Helena Bonham Carter, Antonio Garcia Pascual, Marco Del Negro, Vincent Van Gogh, Piero Della Francesca?

Comment: if thats the case, last names are still the very very last word.

Comment: Be aware that just taking the last 'word' from the name will end up with a bunch of problems unless you are manually reviewing the data.  This is related to http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: In "Charles De Gaulle" the last name is "De Gaulle" :) not "Gaulle". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Gaulle_family

Comment: great point! I think for the database I am working on, there are no surnames I need to deal with..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Oracle DB try this :

```
WITH t AS
  (SELECT name AS l FROM <your query>
  )
SELECT SUBSTR(l,instr(l,' ',-1)+1,LENGTH(l)) FROM t;
```

Comment: Thanks! but when i use that LEFT( ... part, it throws me ORA-00904: "LEFT": invalid identifier error.

Comment: Oh, did not see that was Oracle db. here is a link : https://community.oracle.com/thread/653646?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

[SUBSTRING_INDEX()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring_index-function.php) should work in this case.

```
select name, SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,' ',-1) as lastName from Author;
```

Comment: I'm getting this "ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "SUBSTRING_INDEX": invalid identifier", any ideas?

Comment: This is an Oracle question.